# Magento 2 - Update all images of the products

Tags: product, product-images

0

I would like to update ALL images of my products catalog.

The folder .../pub/media/catalog/product has the images of the products inside a folders with letters of alphabet of numbers:

[image]

If I inspect the code of html the path of the images is inside cache folder:

[image]

And also I have founded images in .../pub/media/import

I have confused. I think that the steps would be:

Upload new images in /pub/media/catalog/product.
Delete images cache from admin panel.
Magento create image thumbnail and image small too. If I delete the cache these images will create automatically?

In this environment I can not do a lot of test but It's a production environment.

Please Could you tell me how to change all images of my product catalog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this doc as i believe this is the easiest way to achieve what you what to do as well as it will give much better idea abot "pub/media/import"

Link: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-import-products-in-magento-2.html

Thanks
Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the first step is download csv file of the products and modify the image columns and import again.

Comment: Great - If it really help you please mark it as correct answer as well - Thanks

Comment: Hi! I have a problem to download the csv file. The file doesn't appear in the browser and by ftp in .../var/... the size of the export file is 0kb :(